# Controlling electric aux heat and oil heat as two separate stages with an Ecobee 3 Lite

Tags: wiring, thermostat

The problem:
I have an older hydronic system at home, powered by heating oil.

Recently, we've installed a heatpump with electric auxiliary heat. Meaning the heatpump will provide heat down to a certain temp, then electric aux heat takes over.

I know the ecobee can control two stages of aux heat.

When wiring the older system to RH, W2 on the ecobee - the electric (new) aux heat - does not engage anymore.

Why do I want this ?
When outdoor temps drop below 30°F, the electric aux heat isn't so great, and it works on and on without providing the results I'd expect.

I'd like to have a solution where:
Cold - heatpump for heat
colder - electric aux heat (stage 1 aux)
very cold - oil heat (stage 2 aux)

I'd like to control the above using the ecobee only, without the need for a second, oil-heat-only tstat.

Thank you.

Comment: What does having your second stage - colder - electric aux heat (stage 1 aux) - buy you?  The electric aux is still going to cost you more than using the oil-fired hydronic heat isn't it, at least in most parts of the country?

Comment: @SteveSh oil heat still useful if air handler fan broken or certain other situations. Electric useful if you are out of oil.

Comment: Sure,  There are always corner cases.  But I think a 2 stage heating system, with a heat pump being the primary mode of heating, and oil-fired hydronic being the secondary or aux heat, makes the most sense recurring cost wise.

Comment: Is there a reason you're sticking to an air-to-air system for your heat pump and electric aux heat, given that your oil system is hydronic and not forced-air?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel : the hydronic system is the old one, the force air is the new one. I would have been happy to do away with the old, but the forced air - ins't cutting it. once it drops bellow 30F, the rooms will cool down by 3 degrees F, before starting to warm up. this process takes can take 30 minutes.

Comment: and, while not a big deal if the living room gets from 67 -> 65F and then starts warming up, but in the bedrooms, getting 30 minutes of cold air off the vents, in the midst of winter at 4am, just does not make sense.

Comment: @SteveSh , yes, that's how I seem to have ended up. the extra $3K I paid for the electric aux heat - proved to be waste of money. I could have done with just heatpump and oil for aux heat. lesson learned..

Comment: @G_G -- what did you get for a heat pump? It sounds like you got a crummy old one that has really poor low ambient capability :/

Comment: @G_G - A non-common arrangement with a heat pump is to replace the aux heating coils in the air handler with a hydronic water to air heat exchanger. Wired/controlled  correctly, that allows your hot water heating system to provide the aux heat using the same ductwork as is used by the heat pump/AC.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I have an ecoer, and it's pretty good. it does the job. during the day I could run it when it's 30F outside, without issues - in the living room. at night - as heatpumps go, as my ducts run in an non-insulated attic, we get cold air in the bedrooms for longer than I'd expect. and - the same occurs even with the electric aux heat.

Comment: @G_G  -- I'd fix the ducts in the attic problem first then work on the thermostat -- uninsulated ducts in vented attics are not fun when you're trying to cool your house in the heat of summer

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the cuts are newly installed and well insulated. the next step would be to insulate the attic itself, an idea I'm not a big fan of - but, having the attic well insulated will indeed make a difference.

Comment: Simplest fix is two thermostats,. Since the ecobee can interface to smart home systems, another solution is to have that watching for the second temperature and tripping a relay, as a virtual thermostat.

Answer (score 3):

The ecobee 3 lite clearly shows in the [specifications](https://www.ecobee.com/en-us/smart-thermostats/smart-wifi-thermostat/#Features-and-Specs) that it supports 2 stages for heating and 2 stages for cooling. So it should be able to handle heat pump regular + heat pump electric aux. heat **or** heat pump regular + hydronic, but not all 3 systems together.

In practice, I think the 3-stage configuration is going to be relatively rare. If a heating system is designed properly and sized correctly for your house size/insulation/typical weather conditions, it *should* be able to keep up with needs for the house. In fact, the only times the second stage should be needed are:

- First stage not usable - this does happen with heat pumps at some temperature. That temperature varies by system and has been improving. But there is a limit, and systems (in general, not just heat pumps and HVAC) are designed to handle 95% or 98% or something like that, so there will be occasional days that it just gets too cold for it work.
- Recovery after a failure. Should be rare. (If you go away for vacation, you wouldn't want to turn the system totally off, just set it a low setting, because you want to avoid coming home to frozen pipes.)
- First stage just can't keep up. If that happens, and it isn't too cold for the first stage to run properly, then you either left doors and windows open or the system is way undersized.

So it is hard to see where the third stage would really come in to play for *most* users. Since you are not happy with the electric aux. heat, I would just wire up the oil heat to stage 2 and be done. That also gives you the option that if you have a power outage and an appropriately installed, but relatively small, generator, you can run the oil heat, because it won't need nearly as much electricity as the heat pump and the electric aux. (toaster) heat is useless when running on a small generator.

---

##### Frame Challenge

Based on comments that this is something that might need to get done periodically based on outside temperatures, but with the implication that human control is OK, as long as it isn't as elaborate as moving the thermostat wires on the thermostat itself:

Just wire up a switch!

You can find something small (since this is low voltage, low current) or just use an ordinary 3-way switch.

Common screw goes to W2 into the thermostat.
Switched screw 1 goes to the electric aux. heat wire.
Switched screw 2 goes to the hydronic system wire.

And when you want to change modes - from electric aux. to hydronic because you think it will be more productive, from hydronic to electric aux. because it is "good enough" or because you are running low on oil - just flip the switch!

Comment: that's where I'm at indeed, when it gets bellow 30F in daytime (implying well bellow that at night), I re-arrange the wiring in the ecobee. but that's not a real solution as during a week, this may need to be done a few times.

Comment: the fact the ecobee knows what is the outdoor temp, as it's connected to a weather service, is what I was hoping could save me. however - the wiring does not work out. the ecobee already makes decisions about when to engage aux heat - according to outdoor temp.

Answer (score 3):

A two-stage thermostat might normally make its decision about calling for the second stage of heat based on how far the present temperature is from the setpoint, or based on a timeout if it has been calling for stage 1 heat without attaining the setpoint. Your use case is different though: you describe a scenario in which you know, based on the outdoor temperature, that the stage 2 electric resistance heat will be inadequate and assistance from the oil/hydronic system will be needed.

A temperature-controlled relay could help you achieve this. When I search for that term online I find a variety of solutions ranging from bare PCB kits on ebay/amazon/etc to industrial control devices from automation suppliers. An ordinary non-programmable thermostat mounted outdoors could even fit the bill (if it'll allow you to program a set point this low!).

Two operating modes come to mind. You can choose either one by the way you arrange the wiring. Because the Ecobee is powered by the forced air furnace while the hydronic system has its own separate 24 volt transformer, you'll have to either arrange things so that the two transformers are in phase or else use a relay to interface with the hydronic system. I'm omitting a wiring diagram in hopes that you'll be able to work out that part on your own.

##### Electric heat with hydronic too

I like this arrangement because it implies the forced-air system won't be blowing entirely unheated air.

Arrange the temperature-controlled relay so that, when the outdoor temperature is below your trigger point, the W2 signal from the Ecobee goes to both the furnace W2 input and also to the hydronic system.

The result is that when the Ecobee decides to turn on the heat it'll call for stage 1 heat pump first. At some point it'll decide that stage 2 is required. The stage 2 call will be delivered to the electric resistance heat no matter what; it'll go to the hydronic system also if the outdoor temperature is cold enough.

##### Electric heat OR hydronic heat, but never both

For this you'll need a "dual throw" relay. Wire it so that its common goes to the Ecobee W2 output, the normally closed terminal goes to the furnace W2 input, and the normally open terminal goes to the hydronic system.

With this arrangement when the Ecobee decides stage 2 heat is needed the relay will control whether that stage 2 calls goes to the resistance heat OR to the hydronic heat.

Comment: that was my "worry", so to speak, that this issue cannot be resolved without wiring work and/or relays. I mean, it can be done of course. and I was under the impression the ecobee would not be able to power HP+AUX+OIL.

Comment: "heat blowing cold air" is my main issue indeed. I find the temps in the room can drop by as 3F before hot air blows, which defeats the purpose of "warming up the house".  my ducts are well insulated, but run inside an uninsulated attic.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is separate thermostats. The high-efficiency heat pump is set for desired temperature. The old gas system is set several degrees colder, so it only comes on if the heat pump has failed or is unable to keep up --  acting more as a backup to protect the plumbing more than anything else.

If they both wind up running at once, that's fine; as soon as the system can keep up with demand again the furnace will drop out.

Much less complicated than trying to deal with more complicated (and fallible) systems and logic. It may mean I'm briefly less comfortable. If that happens I can turn up the gas system's thermostats temporarily.

Over 90% if the functionality for less than 10% of the effort and 0% of the money. Even for a home automation hobbyist, that's hard to beat.

Comment: This is what my daughter did in her house.  Only I think she controls the HWBB boiler manually through a separate T-stat.  Like you said, simpler than dealing with multiple 24 VAC systems.

Answer (score 0):

`I'd like to have a solution where`:

1- Cold - heatpump for heat

2- colder - electric aux heat (stage 1 aux)

3-very cold - oil heat (stage 2 aux)`

1- would be connected to the **O/B** terminal on the ecobee and runs heat pump systems, O/B controls the reversing valve, which tells your compressor to switch between heating and cooling.

2- would be connected to **W1** and runs the electric heater

3- **OR** would be connected to **W2** and runs the oil furnace

**They do not run at same time**

Per manual: Important note for owners of dual-fuel HVAC systems

Also known as packaged or hybrid systems, dual-fuel HVAC systems are made up of an electric heat pump and a secondary heat source, usually a gas furnace that provides reliable, uninterrupted heating on very cold days. If you have a dual-fuel system, during thermostat setup it is very important that you select

**Disable** on the Allow the Heat Pump and Aux Heat to run simultaneously screen to avoid damage to your heat pump.

### UPDATE:

As per ecobee it is not advised to run two heating sources at same time.

To overcome that problem, and still be able to use electric heat **OR** oil heat, you become the chooser.

You will need to install small switch to disconnect the W1 and connect W2 on the thermostat so you do not have to open it each time to do so,

Comment: hmm, in terms of wiring, which would go into w1, and w2 in this scenario ?

Comment: I really, really don't think this will work.

Comment: actually the answer is "yes", to the above. that is how I have things wired - but in the config - electric aux heat does not get engaged, as the ecobee can't seem to handle powering up both aux heat, and oil heat. (but not simultaneously of course).

Comment: @G_G so there is a problem with wiring, do you have two 24 Volt transformers

Comment: @G_G the **C wire** has to connect Electric heat control board and the boiler Direct, not on Ecobee) as it stands right now, you are using the R+C from the boiler, so the electric heater relay does not get power. To test, disconnect the W2 and see if the electric heater is now working

Comment: That is indeed the case @Ruskes , as long as the oil heat w2 is disconnected - the electric aux heat works. 
I was not sure if this is an issue with the wiring, or - this setup cannot work unless the wiring or the relays are changed.

Comment: @G_G I see you have two highly accepted answers. Do they help you ? or shall we continue

Comment: @Ruskes, they do help -  but you point about a possible problem in the wiring is something I'm out to solve here. I'm looking for the least intrusive way to have the ecobee control all three sources of heat.

Comment: at the base of it - it seems like a power issue, meaning - the ecobee does not get enough power in order to control all three: heat pump heat + aux heat + oil heat. but I might be wrong.

Comment: @G_G per ecobee, to prevent damage to your system, it will not run heating from multiple sources at same time. `See my updated answer`

Comment: No, you don't need a switch for W1 vs. W2. The thermostat takes care of that. You need a switch (see my answer) if you want to have two different connections for W2.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact wrong, the W1 goes to electric heater, the W2 goes to oil heater, the ecobee does not know who is who

Comment: W1 goes to regular Heat Pump. W2 goes to another source, either electric resistance inside the heat pump or hydronic boiler

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact this is where you are wrong, the O/B is for the regular heat pump

Comment: No. O/B tells the heat pump to do heating vs cooling.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Exactly, it uses O/B to reverse the compressor into heating, has nothing to do with Aux heating that is only turned on if the temp delta exceeds the capability

Comment: One more time... O/B in mode (I think "open") says W1 - cooling. O/B in the other mode days W1 - heat source 1 (in this case regular heat pump) and W2 - heat source 2 (either aux electric heat or hydronic... With no way to control both from THIS thermostat)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I do not have W1 or W2 connected, just O/B and it is heating when asked for! Magic ?

Comment: thanks everyone. I may contact ecobee and ask whether they sell a model that can control three heat source - which is my case. heatpump, electric aux, and oil. 


any other solution - while valid, is not something I'd consider optimal, though my use case is a bit odd, and may have been caused due to non-optimal pre-install survey  by the the hvac pro, and my own ignorance.

Comment: @Ruskes What thermostat do you have? What other wires are connected? The Ecobee manual is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution get a 3h 2c t stat, they do make em, you can dictate what heat it is, if the equipment or stat controls blower ect ect. Bite the bullet get a big ol vision pro 9000. Had a customer with an ecobee and duel fuel sucker was nice to set up I'd imagine it would help in your case too.

Comment: Your answer is a bit terse.  Could you expand it by describing what the two objects are or posting their pictures or both.